# How to create a circular polygon pour cutout in Altium Designer?

Tags: pcb-design, altium

It is possible to choose "polygon pour cutout" from place menu and create one by clicking multiple points. but how can I create a circular one?

[image: like this]

I am using Platform Build 26245.

Comment: I had the same question for updating the pour after adding vias, until I found Tools->Polygon Pours->Repour Selected.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Create simple circle with Utility Tools, where you want it, select it, then go to Tools-> Convert->Create Cutout from Selected Primitives.

Comment: Nice. I could do it. very creative method!